# How to query Google Analytics without viewId

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-data-api

Seems like Universal Analytics is deprecated and new version of Google analytics doesnt provide a viewId?

Does anyone know how to get google analytics data without having a viewId?

```
  googleAuth.authenticate(authOptions, function (err, token) {
        axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A219265842&start-date=${startDate}&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Acountry&access_token=${token}`)
            .then(analyticsData => {
              
                // res.json(analyticsData)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    });
```

This code was working up until few weeks ago with existing google analytics accounts with viewId.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en

> "Universal Analytics refers to the previous generation of Analytics.
> This was the default property type for websites prior to October 14,
> 2020."

Comment: Have you checked the analytics data api? https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data

Comment: @DaImTo not recommended for production

Comment: This is the only option currently.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for you answers. Finally I figured it out using the link you provided.

Comment: If you figured it out make sure to answer your own question you may help someone else.

Comment: @DaImTo just did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue:

```
googleAuth.authenticate(authOptions, function (err, token) {
        var data = {
            "entity": {
                "propertyId": "YOUR_PROPERTY_ID"
            },
            "dateRanges": [
                {
                    "startDate": startDate,
                    "endDate": "today"
                }
            ],
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "deviceCategory"
                }
            ],
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "name": "totalUsers"
                }
            ]
        };

        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport?key=${keys.GOOGLE_API_KEY}`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
            data: data
        };

        axios(config)
.then(res=>{
console.log(res)
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))

})
```